# FindControl of a Textbox in a UserControl OnRowUpdate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webusercontrol

Hi I've got an error after clicking update and triggering the OnRowUpdate event..
what is the right format of getting the value of a textbox in a usercontrol?

> Error  55  'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for
>   'PlanID' and no extension method 'PlanID' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference

```
protected void grd_Plan_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            string PlanCode =((UserControl)Grid_Plan.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ucPlanID")).PlanID;
        }

//usercontrol code behind

public string PlanID
        {
            get
            {
                return txtPlanID.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                txtPlanID.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
UserControl ucPlanID = (UserControl)Grid_Plan.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ucPlanID");
if (ucPlanID != null)
{
   string PlanCode = ((TextBox)ucPlanID.FindControl("PlanID")).Text;
}
```

Considering, `PlanID` is the ID of your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the control using ClientId. Please note that if newer .Net framework version, you can set client ID mode to static and this will ensure that client ID and the name you give to your control is same.